# Excel: Selective duplicates removal

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I want to remove some duplicates, but not all. Let me give you an example below:

```
 A  B
 UK James
 UK Coco
 UK Lydia
 UK Matthew
 US Max
 US Kim
 US Anna
 FR Marie
 FR Lin
```

I want to turn the columns above into the following:

```
 C  D 
 UK James
    Coco
    Lydia
    Matthew
 US Max
    Kim
    Lulu
 FR Marie
    Lin
```

Initially, I tried the 'remove duplicates' option in Excel, but I wanted to have Column A organised as in Column C.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: copy paste A:B into C:D sort on C.  Then use conditional formatting with the rule: `=C2=C1` applied to C:C with the custom format of `;;;`

Comment: That conditional formatting idea if a nice one. But I always used the solution below because I hate having to look at formulas in two places.

Comment: Would a pivot table fit your needs? It performs exactly this kind of grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A is sorted, then you can use `=IF(A2=A1,"",A2)`

[image: Screenshot of excel with the foprmula shown]

Basically you compare if the row above it is the same. If it is, shown an empty cell, if it if a different value then show that.

Comment: It's a brilliant idea to use a if statement! Makes perfect sense!

Comment: But, what if A is not sorted? For example, A11 is UK ~, which should be in A6.

Comment: if A11 was UK then it would show a single line with UK again. Not much choice here unless you want to allow changing the sequence of named in D. In which case sort on either A or C would work.